# Golang - Testing HTTP Request in Method

Tags: go, tdd

I'm a little confused when it comes to testing in Go. I've read that abstracting to interfaces should be the ideal way to go in some cases, in other cases I see TestTables. I'm not too sure when to apply either one. For instance, how would one go about testing the function below.

```
type User{
    Name string           `json:"name"`
    IsMarried bool        `json:"isMarried"`
    Nicknames []string    `json:"nicknames"`
}

func (u *User) Create() (*http.Response, error) {
    data, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    urll := EndpointBase+"/users"

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, urll,  bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := auth.Session.Client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp, nil
}
```

Comment: Why not provide a fake HTTP server serving the /users endpoint. This is dead simple with net/http/httptest.Server. Just inject the test servers URL as ENdpointBase like Adrian suggested. And than combine this with a table driven test to cover all the possibilities like all fine, user exist, server error, whatever. But this function is just a bit of glue code and testing this in unit tests adds not much value.

Comment: Table-based tests and interfaces solve different problems. You'll often use both. Not either-or.

Comment: @Volker and Flimzy thanks for clarifying the differences as well as how this method may not fully benefit from a unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstracting to interfaces and table-driven tests are unrelated concepts that are commonly both used.

You would abstract to interfaces for your dependencies so that you can mock/stub them as needed (in this case, your dependencies are whatever you're calling with HTTP, whatever auth is, and whatever the global EndpointBase is).

Table-driven tests allow you to write multiple test cases more efficiently with less repeated code in your test.

I'd say that unit testing this function won't have much value though, because it's such a thin wrapper around an HTTP call. An integration test would be more useful, in which case abstracting to interfaces wouldn't help with *testing* (though it could be a good design decision anyway).

Comment: Hey @Adrian, thanks for your answer. So in my case, assuming `auth.Session.Client` creates a HttpClient with a `Do` function that makes the request and `EndpointBase` is just a string to an HTTP endpoint, how would I go about using an integration test for this?

Comment: An integration test, by nature, would test how the application actually works. Nothing would change. You'd just make an automated request and ensure that everything works correctly. You might point `EndpointBase` at a preproduction endpoint rather than production if that's available.